# Date not updating after change of a month

Tags: angular, typescript, date-pipe

I just making a simple view where I can Change a month :

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchToPrevMonth()"><</button>
{{currentDate|date:'MMMM'}}
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchToNextMonth()">></button>
```

and then in my .ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.currentDate = new Date();
}

switchToNextMonth() {
 this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth()+1)
 this.cdRef.detectChanges()
}

switchToPrevMonth() {
this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth()-1)
this.cdRef.detectChanges()
}
```

but it doesn't refresh the date - I made it work by creating a methode getDate() that uses DatePipe in ts(look code below) and returns a string but would like to know why the first case didn't work and if there is a way to make it work...?:s

code that works:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchToPrevMonth()"><</button>
{{getDate()}}
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchToNextMonth()">></button>
```

.ts:

```
getDate():string{
return this.dp.transform(this.currentDate,"MMMM");
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Angular does not detect any change when the Date object is modified. One way to force change detection is to create a new Date object every time you modify the date. You can see in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbtwpk) that it works without invoking `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` manually (except, maybe, if your component uses `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`).

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentDate: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentDate = new Date();
  }

  switchToNextMonth() {
    this.incrementMonth(1);
  }

  switchToPrevMonth() {
    this.incrementMonth(-1);
  }

  private incrementMonth(delta: number): void {
    this.currentDate = new Date(
      this.currentDate.getFullYear(),
      this.currentDate.getMonth() + delta,
      this.currentDate.getDate());
  }
}
```

Comment: that was great ty alot

Comment: This is gold. Even before trying this code, I knew that this would work. Thanks